# Limit of succession of function (2 variables)

Tags: analysis, limits, functions

i want to find limit of

$f_n(x,y)=\frac{e^{-ny^2}}{1+x^2+y^2/n}$, for $n\to+\infty$.

I think $f_n\to f=\frac{1}{1+x^2}$ because I plotted it via MatLab. But my first idea was $f_n\to0$ because of $e^{-ny^2}\to0$.

Anyone can explain this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you are investigating the pointwise convergence. For every $y \neq 0$, the numerator tends to zero while the denominator tends to $1+x^2$. Hence...

For $y=0$, the sequence is constant and equal to $\frac{1}{1+x^2}$. To summarize:
$$
\lim_{n \to +\infty} f_n (x,y) =
\begin{cases}
0 & \text{if $y \neq 0$} \\
\frac{1}{x^2+1} &\text{if $y= 0$}
\end{cases}
$$

Comment: yes i was investigating the pointwise convergence. So if i have 2 different limits it doesn't admit a pointwise limit?... uhmm I'm almost sure it's a dumb question ahahah

Comment: @Bombadil See my edit.